# Stateful LSTM in tensorflowJS: Error: Tensor is disposed

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflowjs-converter

Im trying to deploy a model containing a stateful LSTM-cell using TensorflowJS. The model was pretrained in keras and is constructed by:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(80, activation = 'sigmoid'),input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim,activation = 'sigmoid',return_sequences=False,stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(output_dim, activation='sigmoid'))
```

After training the model, I converted it with **tensorflowjs_converter** and imported it in javascript with `tf.loadLayersModel("/fullmodelTF/model.json")`.

When I now try to make a prediction it works for the first call of `model.predict()`. When I try to predict a second time the following error occurs:

```
Error: Tensor is disposed.
```

After examining the model object in the developer console I noticed that in the stateful LSTM layer the property **states_** looks like:

[image]

As you can see one of the internal states got disposed.
How can I avoid this disposal and the resulting error?

When I try to deploy the same model as stateless it works without any problems.

The loop for the predictions in javascript looks like:

```
result=[]
for(var i=0;i<inp.length;i++){
   var tensor =  tf.tensor(inp[i], [1,timesteps,no_features])
   var prediction=this.model.predict(tensor);
   var data = await prediction.data();
   result.append(data)
 }
```

Comment: Could you please show more Js code ?

Comment: Added the JS code snippet for making the predictions. I get the error in the second iteration.